# Лучшие API для работы с погодой PHP

Tags: php, api

Задача стоит в том, чтобы сделать чат-бота который по городу будет возвращать погоду на сегодня. Подскажите, пожалуйста, достойные API для данной реализации(или может знаете как на openweathermap сделать "нормальную" русификацию).
Желательно чтобы были города Украины.
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Как вариант гисметео https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/

Comment: Вчера заходил туда и там нет регистрации в api, а только вход и ссылка на личный кабинет ведет на "/#"

Comment: лучший и нормально работает - https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/  правда локализация, можно в гугле посмотреть

Comment: Хороший вариант вродь, сейчас гляну

Comment: Спасибо, @GENESIS! Мне подошло [Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather) - стоит немного разобраться с документацией и все отлично работает!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/305014)

Comment: Понял. Не могу найти галку напротив ответа, как тогда отмечать комментарии, как правильный ответ?

Comment: Обычно просят в комментариях "оформите как ответ - поставлю галку"

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Тогда попрошу отметить @genesis 'a как ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучший и нормально работает - [developer.yahoo.com/weather](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather) правда локализация, можно в гугле посмотреть